# Is it possible to accept arbitrary extractor as method argument

Tags: scala, type-parameter, extractor, structural-typing

I'd like to reuse existing extractors and compose them. `A => Option[B]` perfectly matches with `B => Option[C]`.

But I'm confused, how could I express such relation in code.

The obvious way is not available for a good reason:

```
type Extractor[F,T] = {
  def unapply(from : F) : Option[T]
}

def bind[A,B,C](l : Extractor[A,B], r : Extractor[B,C]) = new {
  def unapply(from : A) : Option[C] = l.unapply(from).flatMap(r.unapply _)
}
```

scalac reply:

```
Extractors.scala:7: error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
    def unapply(from : A) : Option[C] = l.unapply(from).flatMap(r.unapply _)
                ^
Extractors.scala:3: error: Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement
    def unapply(from : F) : Option[T]
                ^
two errors found
```

Internet says it is expected behaviour due to type erasure.

Is it possible to rephrase the code so it would work properly?

Answer (score 2):

> Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement`

As the error call out, for `structure type` can't refer the `generic type` that defined in outside.

For your example, you can use `trait` to do the same thing, like:

```
trait Extractor[F, T] {
  def unapply(from: F): Option[T]
}

def bind[A, B, C](l: Extractor[A, B], r: Extractor[B, C]) = new Extractor[A, C] {
  override def unapply(from: A): Option[C] = l.unapply(from).flatMap(r.unapply)
}
```

Comment: And how could I match regex extractor for example to newly defined type `Extractor`?

Comment: @ayvango Could you paste your regex extractor?

Comment: `val date = """(\d\d\d\d)-(\d\d)-(\d\d)""".r` 
There are bunch of other predefined extractors. And I'd like to reuse them.

Comment: maybe you can just wrap the custom `Extractor` with your own extractor, like: `new Extractor[String, List[String]] {
      override def unapply(from: String): Option[List[String]] = date.unapplySeq(from)
    }`

Comment: the question was about method to work with arbitrary extractor. possibly with implicit conversion or other means. The language design made quite a challenge in extractor infrastructure usage